# Printer connected to Mac only works if other Mac is turned on

Tags: macos, imac, bluetooth, printing, leopard

I have an old *iMac **G5*** with *Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard)* and a *Canon PIXMA MG5350* printer. It prints without a problem on the old G5. I think the printer is connected via bluetooth.

And now I also have an *iMac **G6*** with *Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)*.

I can print on the printer, but only if the old G5 is turned on. Why?

How can I change this, so that I can print on the G6 when the G5 is turned off?

Comment: Please use proper Mac identifiers. iMac G5 may refer to the G5 PowerPC processor (Generation 3 iMacs) as well as Generation 5 iMacs.

Comment: Can you please add your specific setup? Is the printer connected directly to the "G5" Mac (either physically or via Bluetooth) or do they share the same network (WiFi or LAN)? Also there is no such thing as a "G6" iMac, please refer to "About this Mac" in the Apple menu for the proper identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the printer is connected to your *iMac G5* and you are sharing it over the network. If you use this shared printer as your standard printer at the *Gen. 6 iMac*, it will quit working as soon as you turn off the *iMac G5*. Connect the printer to you WLAN and configure a new printer at the *Gen. 6 iMac*.